# Visual Studio - Performance in Debugging mode v.s. Installed application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there any noticable performance gain, after installing the application vs while you are debugging it in Visual Studio?

I am pointing to C# and WinForms....I know it depends on type of data and controls and processes in the application, but would like to know if there is any.

Comment: During development in VS IDE, you usually compile the project in Debug mode, but installed applications are compiled in Release mode. The latter is optimized (see /optimize csc option).

Comment: What's the motivation of this question? Why do you want to know? Once it's clear, it will be easier to point related details.

Comment: It's a lot more noticeable with web applications than WinForms, however, there is indeed a performance gain regardless.

Comment: the motivation is that I am dealing with a lot of data sturcture and objects and controls..so I hope after release it works a bit faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** Test it.

**Long answer:** Yes, there is a noticeable performance difference. However, given that most developer's machines are built like battle tanks, what is slow on your machine, will probably be even slower on a standard corporate desktop (even if it's no longer running in debug mode).

The only way to know for sure is to try deploying your application to a target machine and measuring the performance.

Comment: Good point! developing on a quad core and running on a obsolete  celeron or pentium 4 is exactly my case in company :P